# Is there a way to pass a generic type to the reducer used in react useReducer hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, typescript3.0

I'm trying to implement a React custom hook for data fetching using this [article](https://artsy.github.io/blog/2018/11/21/conditional-types-in-typescript/).
This custom hook looks like this

```
type Action<T> =
    | { type: "FETCH_INIT" }
    | { payload: T; type: "FETCH_SUCCESS" }
    | { error: string; type: "FETCH_FAILURE" };

interface IState<T> {
    data: T;
    error: string;
    isLoading: boolean;
}

export const useFetch = <T>(initialUrl: string, initialData: T) => {

    const initialState = {
        data: initialData,
        error: "",
        isLoading: false,
    };


    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer<Reducer<IState<T>, Action<T>>>(dataFetchReducer, initialState);
    ...
};
```

### Problem

The problem is when I try to type the `dataFetchReducer` function. I'm not sure how to pass the generic type from `useFetch` to `dataFetchReducer`.

Here is what `dataFetchReducer` currently looks like.

```
const dataFetchReducer = <T>(state: IState<T>, action: Action<T>): IState<T> => {...};
```

I might be overthinking it and React actually pass the generic type from `useReducer` to `dataFetchReducer` but I'm not sure and I don't even how to test this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
export const reducer: <
    TS extends IEntityState<IEntity>,
    T extends IEntity
>(initialEntity: T) => React.Reducer<TS, Actions> = (initialEntity) => {
    return (state, action) =>  {
        switch(action.type) {
            case ActionTypes.GET_ALL:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    entites: action.entites,
                }
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer<React.Reducer<IStudentState, Actions>>
        (reducer<IStudentState, IStudent>(initialStudent), initialState);
```